# In Angular, how to skip further ngIf check if a variable is null, in template

Tags: angular, null

I have this in the template:

```
<div class="icon-action"
          *ngIf="node == null ? false : node.data && node.data.name && !node.parent.data.virtual"
          (click)="delete(node)">
          <img src="./assets/img/cross.png">
</div>
```

but even if node is properly checked, I still sometimes get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')
```

Shouldn't the false just be returned? Somehow, angular proceeds to check for the value node.data, and I don't want it to, because it throws an error if it does. I tried many ways of checking for null, but none worked. I tried

```
*ngIf = "node && node.data && node.data.name && !node.parent.data.virtual)"
```

and

```
*ngIf = "node == null ? false : node.data && node.data.name && !node.parent.data.virtual"
```

and

```
*ngIf = "node !=null && node.data && node.data.name && !node.parent.data.virtual"
```

every time I am getting the same error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify your condition, and also get rid of the error by using the [null chaining operator `?`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining). With that, your `ngIf` can look like this:

```html
<div class="icon-action"
          *ngIf="node?.data?.name && !node?.parent?.data?.virtual"
          (click)="delete(node)">
          <img src="./assets/img/cross.png">
</div>
```

> but even if node is properly checked, I still sometimes get the error:

You are indeed guarding yourself from accessing the `data` on a null `node`, but I did not see any piece of code checking if `node.parent` is null, and the error could be from `node.parent.data`.